# need to copy text(Automatically) of webpage after every refresh

Tags: javascript, php, copy, refresh

i created a website where one particular page, which fetched content from other place , updates in every 5 minutes. now i want to copy all text of that page automatically after every refresh to avoid

> Ctrl+C

each and every time.
i created web in php and i am searching solution in PHP/JavaScript

Comment: On Clipboard so i can paste it anywhere

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)